# Unable load Tensor RT SavedModel after conversion in Tensorflow 2.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt

I have been attempting to convert a [YOLOv3 model implemented in Tensorflow 2](https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2) to Tensor RT by following the tutorial on the NVIDIA website (https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html#worflow-with-savedmodel).

I used the SavedModel approach to make the conversion, and have successfully managed to convert the original model to FP16 and save the result as a new SavedModel. When the new SavedModel is loaded within the same process that the conversion was made in, it is loaded correctly, and I am able to run an inference on an image, however the issue arises when I then attempt to load the FP16 saved model in a new process. When I attempt to do this I get the following errors:

```
2020-04-01 10:39:42.428094: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libnvinfer.so.6
2020-04-01 10:39:42.447415: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libnvinfer_plugin.so.6
Coco names not found, class labels will be empty
2020-04-01 10:39:53.892453: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-04-01 10:39:53.920870: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: TITAN Xp computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.582GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 11.91GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 510.07GiB/s
2020-04-01 10:39:53.920915: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-04-01 10:39:53.920950: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-04-01 10:39:53.937043: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-04-01 10:39:53.941012: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-04-01 10:39:53.972250: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-04-01 10:39:53.976883: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-04-01 10:39:53.976919: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-04-01 10:39:53.978525: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-01 10:39:53.978833: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-04-01 10:39:54.112532: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2999115000 Hz
2020-04-01 10:39:54.114178: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55f3a70 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-04-01 10:39:54.114208: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-04-01 10:39:54.219842: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x555e230 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-04-01 10:39:54.219872: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): TITAN Xp, Compute Capability 6.1
2020-04-01 10:39:54.220896: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: TITAN Xp computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.582GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 11.91GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 510.07GiB/s
2020-04-01 10:39:54.220936: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-04-01 10:39:54.220948: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-04-01 10:39:54.220981: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-04-01 10:39:54.220998: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-04-01 10:39:54.221013: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-04-01 10:39:54.221029: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-04-01 10:39:54.221039: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-04-01 10:39:54.222281: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-01 10:39:54.232890: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-04-01 10:39:54.636732: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-04-01 10:39:54.636779: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2020-04-01 10:39:54.636786: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2020-04-01 10:39:54.638840: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 11240 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: TITAN Xp, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-04-01 10:40:26.366595: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libnvinfer.so.6
2020-04-01 10:40:31.509694: E tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/trt_logger.cc:42] DefaultLogger INVALID_ARGUMENT: getPluginCreator could not find plugin BatchedNMS_TRT version 1
2020-04-01 10:40:31.509767: E tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/trt_logger.cc:42] DefaultLogger safeDeserializationUtils.cpp (259) - Serialization Error in load: 0 (Cannot deserialize plugin since corresponding IPluginCreator not found in Plugin Registry)
2020-04-01 10:40:31.513205: E tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/trt_logger.cc:42] DefaultLogger INVALID_STATE: std::exception
2020-04-01 10:40:31.513262: E tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/trt_logger.cc:42] DefaultLogger INVALID_CONFIG: Deserialize the cuda engine failed.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am unsure as to what is causing this issue, and the only thread I have been able to find that brings up this issue is on the nvidia dev forum and does not provide an answer. (https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/getplugincreator-could-not-find-plugin-batchednms-trt-version-1/84205/3)

My question therefore, is; why does the SavedModel not load when the loading code is executed in a different process than the conversion code? And, how could I load my Tensor RT model without having to convert it from the non-TensorRT model each time?

Here is the code that was used to convert the model and the inference output when the converted model is loaded in the same process.

**Code**

```
import os
from os.path import join as pjoin

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_io
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
from tensorflow.python.framework import convert_to_constants

from caipy_services_backend.models import Yolov3
from caipy_services_backend.models.yolov3.utils import freeze_all

# Clear any previous session.
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()


def my_input_fn():
    for _ in range(1):
        inp1 = np.random.normal(size=(1, 416, 416, 3)).astype(np.float32)
        # inp2 = np.random.normal(size=(8, 16, 16, 3)).astype(np.float32)
        yield [inp1]


def convert_saved_model_and_reload(input_saved_model_dir, output_saved_model_dir):
    conversion_params = trt.DEFAULT_TRT_CONVERSION_PARAMS
    conversion_params = conversion_params._replace(
        max_workspace_size_bytes=(1 << 32))
    conversion_params = conversion_params._replace(precision_mode="FP16")
    conversion_params = conversion_params._replace(
        maximum_cached_engines=100)

    converter = tf.experimental.tensorrt.Converter(
        input_saved_model_dir=input_saved_model_dir, conversion_params=conversion_params)
    converter.convert()

    converter.build(input_fn=my_input_fn)
    converter.save(output_saved_model_dir)

    saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(
        output_saved_model_dir, tags=["serve"])
    graph_func = saved_model_loaded.signatures["serving_default"]
    frozen_func = convert_to_constants.convert_variables_to_constants_v2(
        graph_func)
    input_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.normal(size=(1, 416, 416, 3)).astype(np.float32))
    output = frozen_func(input_data)[0].numpy()
    print(output)
```

**Output**

```
[[[0. 0. 1. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).trt_engine_resources.TRTEngineOp_3._serialized_trt_resource_filename
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).trt_engine_resources.TRTEngineOp_4._serialized_trt_resource_filename
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).trt_engine_resources.TRTEngineOp_5._serialized_trt_resource_filename
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).trt_engine_resources.TRTEngineOp_0._serialized_trt_resource_filename
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).trt_engine_resources.TRTEngineOp_7._serialized_trt_resource_filename
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).trt_engine_resources.TRTEngineOp_1._serialized_trt_resource_filename
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).trt_engine_resources.TRTEngineOp_2._serialized_trt_resource_filename
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).trt_engine_resources.TRTEngineOp_6._serialized_trt_resource_filename
WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
```

**And here is the code that is causing the error**

```
def load_tensor_rt_model(saved_model_dir):
    saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(
        saved_model_dir, tags=["serve"])
    graph_func = saved_model_loaded.signatures["serving_default"]
    frozen_func = convert_to_constants.convert_variables_to_constants_v2(
        graph_func)
    input_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.normal(size=(1, 416, 416, 3)).astype(np.float32))
    output = frozen_func(input_data)[0].numpy()
    print(output)
```

Any help with this issue would be very much appreciated.

UPDATE: The issues described in this question are being caused by the use of converter.build(). When the converted is saved without being built it can then be loaded without issue. I still don't know however why build is causing this issue.

Computer spec:

- GPU: NVIDIA TitanXp
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Package versions:

- NVIDIA graphics driver: 440.59
- CUDA: 10.1.243-1 amd64
- CUDNN: 7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.1
- libnvinfer-dev: 6.0.1-1+cuda10.1
- libnvinfer-plugin-dev: 6.0.1-1+cuda10.1
- python: 3.6.9
- tensorflow: 2.1.0

Comment: Any luck with solution?

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf No luck yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that this happens because the libnvinfer_plugin.so.* doesn't get loaded when infering using a saved engine (I'm guessing it gets loaded and used when convert.build() is used).

I forced a plugins init using `trt.init_libnvinfer_plugins(None,'')` (import tensorrt as trt) at the start of my infer function and that happened to solve this particular error.

Comment: In 2024, on Windows, using TensorRT 8.6, this is still very valid answer. Building an engine from an onnx model and running inference worked fine. Restarting the process and loading the already built model did not work unless initLibNvInferPlugins is called. Thanks.